# Consultar columna concatenada

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta sql que funciona bien.

```
 SELECT
    C.id AS id,
    concat(C.apellido_paterno," ",C.apellido_materno," ",C.nombres) AS 
    nombre_completo,
    C.agente AS agente,
    G.genero AS genero
    FROM cliente_tabla AS C
    JOIN genero_tabla AS G ON G.id = C.genero
```

Pero cuando intento hacer la siguiente consulta

```
  SELECT
    C.id AS id,
    concat(C.apellido_paterno," ",C.apellido_materno," ",C.nombres) AS 
    nombre_completo,
    C.agente AS agente,
    G.genero AS genero
    FROM cliente_tabla AS C
    JOIN genero_tabla AS G ON G.id = C.genero 
    WHERE nombre_completo LIKE "%PACO%"
```

arroja Unknown column 'nombre_completo' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no puedes poner un alias en un where tienes que volver a poner el concat completo

```
SELECT
    C.id AS id,
    concat(C.apellido_paterno," ",C.apellido_materno," ",C.nombres) AS 
    nombre_completo,
    C.agente AS agente,
    G.genero AS genero
    FROM cliente_tabla AS C
    JOIN genero_tabla AS G ON G.id = C.genero 
    WHERE concat(C.apellido_paterno," ",C.apellido_materno," ",C.nombres) LIKE "%PACO%"
```

Comment: Te refieres a que a una concatenacion no se le puede poner un alias  en un where o que no se puede poner un alias en un where?

Comment: A que no puedes usar un alias en un where

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es hacer :

```
select *  from ( SELECT
    C.id AS id,
    concat(C.apellido_paterno," ",C.apellido_materno," ",C.nombres) AS 
    nombre_completo,
    C.agente AS agente,
    G.genero AS genero
    FROM cliente_tabla AS C
    JOIN genero_tabla AS G ON G.id = C.genero ) as OTRATABLA 
where  OTRATABLA.nombre_completo LIKE "%PACO%" ;
```

Comment: No entiendo que intentas hacer. Me podrías explicar y ademas aparece este error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: El error que te tiro esta en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias es porque me olvide de agregar el alias a la subquery. Podes crear select anidados en casos así, para no volver a usar el concat en el where.

Answer (score 1):

Como veo dos respuestas anteriores que son correctas, tan solo quería decirte que es más cómodo usar concat_ws así:

```
select concat_ws(" ",C.apellido_paterno,C.apellido_materno,C.nombres) AS nombre_completo from cliente_tabla
```

Espero haber servido de ayuda